# Intermittent behaviour on SELECT during post-insert trigger (MySQL 5.7)

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm facing a strange behaviour in an `AFTER INSERT` trigger I created.

I have two tables on two different schemas - one of them is the log of the usage our customers perform against our APIs. The other one is used to mark which transactions should or not be billable. If a certain call was made before (based on some equal parameters), we mark this transaction as "non-billable".

Here is an excerpt of how I perform this validation (extracted from my trigger):

```
SELECT tl_duplicated.transaction_id 
INTO @duplicated_transaction_id
FROM log_mbs.transaction_log AS tl_duplicated
WHERE tl_duplicated.gc_id = NEW.gc_id
  AND tl_duplicated.function_name = NEW.function_name
  AND tl_duplicated.report_options = NEW.report_options
  AND tl_duplicated.source = NEW.source
  AND tl_duplicated.result_code = NEW.result_code
  AND ((tl_duplicated.i_person_id = NEW.i_person_id) OR (tl_duplicated.i_person_id IS NULL AND NEW.i_person_id IS NULL))
  AND tl_duplicated.billing_code = NEW.billing_code 
  AND tl_duplicated.date_added <= NEW.date_added
  AND tl_duplicated.date_added >= @billing_start_interval
  AND NOT tl_duplicated.transaction_id = NEW.transaction_id
  LIMIT 1;

IF @duplicated_transaction_id IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET @billable = 0;
    SET @reason_code = CONCAT('DUPLICATED BY ',@duplicated_transaction_id);
ELSE 
    SET @billable = 1;
    SET @reason_code = '';
END IF;
```

The problem I'm facing is that for 0.5% of the cases (15k in 3.8 million) seems like this "SELECT" isn't returning data even when it was supposed to.

At first I was thinking if it could be a concurrency problem (two logs inserted at the same time), but I noticed this behaviour happening with transactions that were hours apart from each other. I even tried to use a SQL_NO_CACHE keyword for this select statement to see if I wasn't facing any cache problem, but without success so far.

Can anyone give me a light on what can be happening in this case?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is an example of a transaction with this behaviour. Below is a select statement which shows that the compared fields matches between both transactions tl_1 and tl_2:

```sql
SELECT  
    tl_1.function_name = tl_2.function_name as 'match function_name',
    tl_1.report_options = tl_2.report_options as 'match report_options',   
    tl_1.source = tl_2.source as 'match source',   
    tl_1.result_code = tl_2.result_code as 'match result_code',   
    tl_1.i_person_id = tl_2.i_person_id as 'match i_person_id',  
    tl_1.billing_code = tl_2.billing_code as 'match billing_code',   
    tl_1.date_added, tl_2.date_added 
FROM 
    log_mbs.transaction_log as tl_1 
INNER JOIN 
    log_mbs.transaction_log as tl_2 
WHERE 
    tl_1.transaction_id = '93221R499739' 
    AND tl_2.transaction_id = '93181R499869';
```

```
    +---------------------+----------------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
    | match function_name | match report_options | match source | match result_code | match i_person_id | match billing_code | date_added          | date_added          |
    +---------------------+----------------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
    |                   1 |                    1 |            1 |                 1 |                 1 |                  1 | 2023-06-10 00:35:39 | 2023-06-10 00:38:54 |
    +---------------------+----------------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Here are the values added on the billing table.

```
    +----------------+----------+-------------+---------------------+
    | transaction_id | billable | reason_code | date_added          |
    +----------------+----------+-------------+---------------------+
    | 93221R499739   |        1 |             | 2023-06-10 00:35:39 |
    | 93181R499869   |        1 |             | 2023-06-10 00:38:54 |
    +----------------+----------+-------------+---------------------+
```

The second transaction was added ~3 minutes after the first one, so the trigger should have found this one to list as a duplicity.

Comment: Latest version of the 5.7 series? Where is the data selected from here used that you think it's not selecting anything?

Comment: Hi @tadman. Yes, it is the latest version of 5.7. I editted the post to add an example

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: @tadman sorry, I was facing errors when posting this evidence as code. I managed to fix the post and now it is in plain text.

Comment: Use `IF EXISTS (query)` instead of `SELECT INTO @var` and further `IF @var IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: `SQL_NO_CACHE` should not be relevant. (1) the Query cache takes care of itself and (2) the query cache is deprecated.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Answer (score 0):

(not an Answer)

```
AND  ((tl_duplicated.i_person_id = NEW.i_person_id)
              OR  (tl_duplicated.i_person_id IS NULL
                      AND  NEW.i_person_id IS NULL)
           )
```

can be simplified to

```
AND  tl_duplicated.i_person_id <=> NEW.i_person_id
```